# Append multiple xml test reports of google test

Tags: c++, shell, googletest

I'm trying to generate an XML test report for multiple tests created with google tests.

Suppose I have 2 executable files: `/test1.out` `/test2.out`.

To run both of them together, I used a shellscript:

```
#!/bin/sh

/test1.out --gtest_output="xml:testreport.xml"
/test2.out --gtest_output="xml:testreport.xml"
```

I want to append both test reports together but in this case I'll just overwrite the `testreport.xml` of test1 with test2.

Is there a simple way on how to do this ?

Comment: Am I right that you need this feature because of jenkins (as you said in your other post)?. Why don't you just export the results to different files and discover them using junit in your jenkinsfile? (this is absolutely possible)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe running ctest is a valid solution for you:

```
ctest -C Debug -T Test
```

ctest executes all googletests and reports in one xml file.

I needed to extend my cmake files with one line each

```
add_test(NAME TestName1 COMMAND test1)
```

Where test1 is the name of the cmake executable.