# Build and run tests with different jobs

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, continuous-integration, googletest

I have some cpp/header files in Github that I am currently building through 2 Jenkins jobs.

The first Jenkins job will build the tests and the second will run the tests. I could have combined both into one job, but I can't publish the test results of **Google Tests** with JUnit due to this issue [Append multiple xml test reports of google test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73471919/append-multiple-xml-test-reports-of-google-test), so separating both jobs would make it clearer.

My solution was making the test job share the same workspace as the build job and triggering it once the build is stable.

I am new to Jenkins and don't know if this is a typical workflow. Is there any other idea on how to do this or is this reasonable?